# How to read Attribute Name and Dataset Name from HDF5 file in c++, here I dont know what are the attributes are there in HDF5 file

Tags: c++, hdf5

I have one HDF5 file say Select.h5 , But i dont know anything about the file except file name , How to know the attribute name and Dataset Name from this filename using c++

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Using HDFql (http://www.hdfql.com) in C++, you can open an HDF5 file named "example.h5" like this:

```
HDFql::execute("USE FILE example.h5");
```

From there, retrieving the name of objects (i.e. groups, datasets, attributes) stored in group "/" (i.e. root of the HDF5 file) can be done as follows:

```
HDFql::execute("SHOW /");
```

To retrieve only the attributes stored in "/" include the keyword ATTRIBUTE:

```
HDFql::execute("SHOW ATTRIBUTE /");
```

To retrieve all objects that exist in the HDF5 file (starting from "/") use the keyword "LIKE **":

```
HDFql::execute("SHOW / LIKE **");
```

To retrieve all datasets that exist in the HDF5 file (starting from "/"):

```
HDFql::execute("SHOW DATASET / LIKE **");
```

Comment: This command "SHOW" only places the cursor, right? How would one then access the actual attribute and print it to the console, using std::cout for example?

Comment: @MrSquid yes, the command `SHOW` places the result in the cursor by default; you can however redirect the result into a file or memory (i.e. user-defined variable). Example: `SHOW INTO FILE output.txt` or `SHOW INTO MEMORY 0` (`0` being the number assigned to the variable registered beforehand). To access the actual attribute and print it in the console one could do the following (assuming that the result is stored in a cursor): `HDFql::cursorFirst();`, `std::cout << HDFql::cursorGetChar();`

Answer (score 0):

We can achieved this using Group ID , once you have created the HdF5 file Default group will create with name that '/'(which means root group),

so from that group we can get the information of DataSet of HDF5 file using DataSet  metadata we get the Information about the Attributes including its Name